# How to fetch one word at a time from mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, database

Actually, I have created a CMS in which I can insert posts with keywords. I mean I am using a table in mysql database where there is a column named as "keywords".

I want to create categories using keywords separated by comma, to do this I have to fetch one word at a time if there are many words for a particular post, I would like to know the sql query ( or PHP code) I have to use to do so using PHP.

As for example:-
If I have table as I have shown below,

```
Post_id post_title post_keywords

1       first post   PHP 
2       second post  PHP, jquery
3       third post   css, html
4       fourth post  html
```

I would like to create categories according to keywords as shown below:-

```
PHP -> first post        Jquery ->  second post        CSS -> third post
       second post             

html -> third post
        fourth post
```

Means I click php then it should contain two posts "first post" and "second post".

Comment: If you normalize the database properly, you won't have this problem. Use a `post_keywords` table that has one row for each keyword assigned to a post, and then join them.

Comment: I have a user interface in which along with post details I can enter keywords. I want to do everything I discussed above in the background.
I don't have much idea regarding above, can you give me any link for some tutorial?

Comment: google "database normalization tutorial" and you'll find plenty. I've never read any of them, so I can't recommend anything specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your posts table:

```
CREATE TABLE posts
    (`id` int, `title` varchar(11))
;

INSERT INTO posts
    (`id`, `title`) 
VALUES
    (1, 'first post'),
    (2, 'second post'),
    (3, 'third post'),
    (4, 'fourth post')
;
```

Your tags table

```
CREATE TABLE tags
    (`id` int, `tag` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO tags
    (`id`, `tag`)
VALUES
    (1, 'PHP'),
    (2, 'jquery'),
    (3, 'css'),
    (4, 'html')
;
```

And your join table.

```
CREATE TABLE post2tags
    (`postid` int, `tagid` int)
;

INSERT INTO post2tags
    (`postid`, `tagid`)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 3),
    (3, 4),
    (4, 4)
;
```

Then this SQL gets you basically what you want (maybe theorder is different):

```
SELECT t.*, p.*
FROM tags t
INNER JOIN post2tags p2t ON t.id=p2t.tagid
INNER JOIN posts p ON p.id=p2t.postid
ORDER BY t.tag, p.title
```

Here is it in a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62b79/3/0)

This is a many-to-many relationship. Once you understand it you will probably use it often.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following

table Post

```
PostId|PostName|...
     1|First Post|...
     2|Second Post|...
       ...
```

Table Keyword

```
keyID|KeyName
     1|PHP
     2|JQUERY
      ...
```

Table RE_Post_KEY (many to many)

```
PostID|KeyID
     1|1
     1|2
     2|1
     2|2
     ...
```

Comment: I understand it theoretically, but I have not implemented it practically, so I am little bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

While I would agree with the suggestion of normalizing your database, to answer your specific question, you could use `FIND_IN_SET()`:

```
SELECT Post_Title
FROM YourTable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('php', post_keywords)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cdcf/1)

However, if you normalize your database, you would just have to use a simple `JOIN`.

Comment: I opened your link and changed the PHP to html within FIND_IN_SET () it is given just one result but it should have two.

Comment: @CDnDT -- You should normalize your database for the best performance.  However, since you're storing spaces in between your list, you could use `REPLACE` to remove the whitespace.  Here's another fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cdcf/4.  With that said, please consider normalizing your results...